# Передача данных между скриптами в реальном времени Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 2 скрипта - EnemyBehavior и DefaultMovement (поведение противника и игрока). Возникла необходимость в создании окна с очками. При убийстве противника игроку начисляется одно очко. Противники спавнятся в определённом месте, префаб с противниками один. Метод уничтожения противников находится в EnemyBehavior, но т.к. постоянно спавнятся новые противники окно очков хотелось бы прикрутить к игроку (т.е. DefaultMovement). Встала необхдимость постоянно передавать переменную int scoreNumber из EnemyBehavior в DefaultMovement, где та из инта преобразуется в строку для поля с очками. Ответов в интернете много, но не один не подошёл под мою ситуацию с передачей в реальном времени. Вероятнее всего, я чего-то не понял
Код в DefaultMovement предполагался такой (ничего не работает):

```
public Text score;
public int scoreNumber = 0;

 void Update()
    {
      score.text = scoreNumber.ToString();
    }
```

код в EnemyBehavior:

```
 DefaultMovement1 mov = new DefaultMovement1;

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if (target.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            canMove = false;
            if(canShoot)
            {
                canShoot = false;
                CancelInvoke("StartShooting"); 
            }
            Invoke("TurnOffGameObject", 0.5f);
            mov.scoreNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать статическую переменную

```
static int scopeNumber
```

Если это два разных класса то я наверное бы использовал синглтон.
Тут можно ознакомиться: https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php#

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как по мне то замечание лишнее. Его ответ вполне полностью отвечает на вопрос, а синглтон - лишь дополнение и альтернативный ответ который не обязательно освещать полностью.

Comment: @Andrew ответ является не правильным, в Unity есть более хороший способ для изменения данных из одного скрипта в другом. Этот способ я описал ниже

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer 1. ответ является правильным т.к. работает. 2. твой способ написан в моем ответе под пунктом 3 -- даже сразу написал что так себе идея, кроме того дополнил еще и идеей с префабом. 3. Твой способ не будет работать при переходе между уровнями даже если не выгружать из памяти инстанс счетчика - что создает ряд проблем с подобными переходами. То есть твой истинно правильный способ имеет свои недостатки. Не говоря о том что в ряде случаев заасайненый скрипт может сбиваться из инспектора)

Comment: @Andrew при переходе между уровнями? Была такая задача? Для этого существует Playerprefs. Друг, если мы уж заговорили о недостатках, то давай же разберём их. С static'ом мы не сможем изменять переменную из инспектора, а так же появляется куча других проблем, которые могу случится из-за статика

Comment: глупо это делать через гипер-медленный плеер-префс, если дешевле в плане ресурсов просто не выгружать из памяти сам счетчик при переходе на другой уровень)  Не было, я просто показал пример что твой "правильный способ" создает потенциальные проблемы на ровном месте в целом ряде случаев. Истинно правильный способ -- тот, который тебе проблем не создает. Ни практических, ни потенциальных.

Comment: На счёт PlayerPrefs полностью солидарен, и сам давно юзаю кастомную сохранялку, но разве сохранения нескольких байтиков повлияют на производительность? Чел, мы не в 2015, и о таких мелочах думать не стоит

Comment: возьми профайлер и замерь сколько времени занимает сохранение и загрузка данных из плеерпрефс) Я против овероптимизации. Но пользоваться тормозным плеерпрефсом сначала сохраняя, а потом загружая временные данные вместо того что бы просто не выгружать обьект из памяти (1 строчка кода) - это просто глупо. Как с точки зрения чистоты кода, так и с точки зрения перформанса. Но от дискуссии я устал.

Comment: Так, окей. Можно подстраивать в переменную скрипта в рантайме, из-за чего сразуже отпадают все проблемы

Comment: Тот способ который сказал я, он предложен самой Unity и очен удобен, поэтому не вижу смысла пилить всякие костыли.

Comment: В туториалах и документации к юнити все еще можно найти как пользоватся устаревшим тормозным GUI интерфейсом вплоть до самой последней версии юнити.) Это совсем не значит что пользоватся им это хорошая практика. Вобщем... Серьезно, закругляйся.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119631/discussion-between-andrew-and-mr-antonder).

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов решения проблемы на самом деле много.

1. Статический класс со счетом
2. Синглтон-класс со счетом
3. Создать префаб врага на который через инспектор навешен обьект со счетом. И спавнить врагов с этого префаба. (так себе идея, может создавать проблемы в ряде случаев)
4. динамически искать игрока и вытягивать необходимый монобихейвор и при спавне игрока (плохая идея - проблемы с перформансом гарантированны, но сработает) или же при его убивании (то же самое)
5. Создавать врагов через фабрику которая сразу прикручивает доступ к необходимому монобихейвору-счетчику

Вобщем, выбор более чем широкий. Лично я бы выбрал первый или второй вариант. Хотя пятый тоже неплох.

Answer (score 0):

Unity не поддерживает создание объектов через new.

Unity предлогает альтернативу:

Вам нужно создать публичную переменную с именем скрипта к которому вы хотите обратиться, и в инспекторе указать на каком объекте лежит этот скрипт.

Вот пример указания и обращения к скрипту:

Скрипт: **script1**

```
public int hp = 0;
```

Скрипт: **script2**

```
public script1 sc;

void Start(){
sc.hp = 100;
}
```